# Disabling HP 3D driveguard?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, hard-drive-failure

Laptop model: HP dv7t-7000, 1TB 5400rpm Hdd

First off, i know how to disable hp 3d driveguard protection, my question is whether it is a good idea in the following situation:

I will be recording audio from an external 1/8 inch microphone while walking around. To do this, i am closing the lid of the laptop and putting it in my backpack with the microphone cable trailing out and into my hands where i can use it. I have engineered it in such a way that there is no stress on cables, and the laptop does not overheat too bad.

But of course, whenever i move, the hard drive locks and the audio being recorded at that point is lost. So I'm wondering: I have done essentially this with laptops *without* hp driveguard and they were fine. So can I temporarily disable driveguard while my laptop is in my backpack, or would this be a bad idea and I was just lucky before?

Thanks for the help,
Blaine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to you eventually as to whether it's worth the risk - presumably, so long as you're not planning on jogging with it it ought to be OK, though I'd really be tempted to invest in an SSD if you're going to be doing this a lot.

More so if it's a pro rig & the audio is for production. I'm sure the director would be mighty upset if he didn't get sound on an entire day's takes just because the sound guy rammed the drive heads against the platters 5 minutes before wrap.

It might take just one knock too many & you crash the heads & lose more than a couple of minutes of audio.

You can be as careful as you like, but the random guy running past you might not be.

Comment: Thank you. No, this should only be a one time deal or so, just a 14 year old recording audio for interview videos on the go. I'll try to walk slowly and without sudden jerks, and as for the people around me, due to the situation, I don't think it will be much of a problem.

Comment: So I did it and encountered no problems. Successfully got 2 hours of audio recorded to my Laptop HDD

Comment: Cool - glad it worked for you. I'd still go for SSD if you're going to do it often, but for the occasional foray into the field you're probably safe enough.

Comment: finally got the video up. Anyway, just wanted to say thanks, and your advice allowed me to create the first video on this page https://sites.google.com/site/techforteachinghome/videos